# Create Retrofit service class Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

What would be the most appropriate way of creating a retrofit instance?(not necessarily between the 3 options below)
What are the differences between these 3 ways?

**Option 1**

```
object BuffApi {
    val retrofitService : BuffApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(BuffApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
object BuffApi {
    val retrofitService2: BuffApiService = retrofit.create(BuffApiService::class.java)
}
```

**Option 3**

```
class BuffApi {
    val retrofitService: BuffApiService = retrofit.create(BuffApiService::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a chance that you don't call `retrofitService` , or if it's not frequent it is best to Use Option 1 - `val retrofitService : BuffApiService by lazy {` because your program will not initalize the variable `retrofitService` until you access or call it which reduce the memory usage.

in another case Option_2 will help because it is static you don't have to create a new object every time you want to access it and also it is good practice to use a single instance of  Service like (**retrofit**, **repository**) classes.

The ByteCode generation of Option_2 and Option_3 is almost the same: 40 and 64 line: but for Option_1 it is around 146 line